# How redirect to mobile version of site without changing URL?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect

i'm trying to redirect my mobile users and all of small devices users to my mobile version of web site.
but i don't like change my URL.
like below example ,

desktop version : domain.com ( with desktop version of site )

mobile version : domain.com ( with mobile version of site )

Comment: you could do the job via `htaccess`  rewrite URL

Comment: Where *is* your mobile version of the site? We can't give you an accurate answer if you don't tell us where you need to redirect *to*. Is your mobile version a different site or part of the desktop one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all of you for commenting my question.
Now that i write my answer to my self , i found my question's answer.

> **Responsive** design not it's answer. You have to show a **mobile version** of site, not responsive version of site. so using `@media()`
>   not useful.

For this issues , You have to **detect** user's device in your back-end. for example in PHP you can use [mobile-detect](http://mobiledetect.net/).
And you can detect your device and show it's template for that device.

---

Also, mobile detect have a js version. [click here](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/)
I hope you find your answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect means to Change the window location.

since you dont want to have a seperate mobile site,
The Only feasible solution is to use a good responsive ui framework like bootstrap. but in your tags you mentioned wordpress and i feel most of the wp themes are in fact responsive.

Anyways, use bootstrap if you would like to design a responsive site.or another alternative would be to write all css using media queries.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Responsive is good thing.

But on some sites we want to change all ui & ux so need a different output.

Comment: it is still very simple. just write html for mobile and desktop together in the same page, And in your css media queries, set `display:none` to all the elemtents that do not belong to that device.

Comment: it's bad practice to hide big sections on page with css...
The mobile not need hidden section and it's waste of bandwidth & rendering time.

Comment: @MosheHarush i know it is.. but just look at the requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the theme of the site for this "on the fly".

You can do it with code but it's too long, use this plugin instead [device theme switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/device-theme-switcher/)

Answer (score 0):

URls for both should be same and they are same in their case as well. Well done !

Now, for automatically rendering the specific layout, take help of media queries.

Refer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

They define the specific width range and pick up those specific styles only.

So you have a lot of work to do.

This is a optimal way to work and this is termed as responsive design.

You can find `n` no of tutorials for same. But to experiment just work with one or two media queries.

Also, read about meta tags which enables to pick those media queries written in stylesheet https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

When customizing a page on WordPress, at the bottom left corner, you can see how your website will look like in phones or tablets.

Also, some page builders like Elementor, allow you to control what sections to appear on what screens.

A better way to state your question question would be, how to make a page responsive?

When reading about `Grid Systems`, you'll be amazed at how a simple change to the orientation of your divs, can make a huge user experience difference. 
When using a framework that uses `Grid Systems`, `Bootstrap` being one of the popular ones, you can imagine any screen divided into 12 columns (grids). Then you can specify how many parts a div takes on each screen size by adding classes. For example, `<div class = "col-sm-6 col-lg-3" </div>` will cover have the screen (horizontally) in small screens (6 being half of 12) and a quarter of large screens.

The reason behind this peocess is to eleminate right and left scrolling which makes it easier to navigate. 
Hope this gives you a little overview of what you need to be looking for to make mobile-friendly websites. Good luck!